# my 'posts' state is not rendering even after getting data in console

Tags: reactjs

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { db } from "../../Firebase"

import "../../styles/students.css"

function Students() {

```
const [posts, setposts] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('students').onSnapshot(snapshot => {

        setposts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => (doc.data().email)))
        console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => (doc.data().email)))
        console.log(posts)
    })


}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <h1>WELCOME STUDENTS</h1>
        <div className="contianer students">
            {posts.map((item) => {

                <h1>{item.email}</h1>
            })
            }
        </div>


    </div>
)
```

}

export default Students

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot to use return keyword in map

Use this

```
<div>
    <h1>WELCOME STUDENTS</h1>
    <div className="contianer students">
        {posts.map((item) => {

            return (<h1>{item.email}</h1>)
        })
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div>
    <h1>WELCOME STUDENTS</h1>
    <div className="contianer students">
        {posts.map((item) =>  <h1>{item.email}</h1>)
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you find it helpful , please upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
const [posts, setposts] = useState([])
useEffect(async() => {
    await db.collection('students').onSnapshot(snapshot => {

        setposts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => (doc.data().email)))
        console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => (doc.data().email)))
        console.log(posts)
    })


}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <h1>WELCOME STUDENTS</h1>
        <div className="contianer students">
            {posts.map((item) => {

               return <h1>{item.email}</h1>
            })
            }
        </div>


    </div>
)
}
```

You Forgot To Write `Return` Statement In Map Function. Use `Async` Function  and `Await`.To synchorize its Recommended approch.